# .NET Wrapper Class

Tags: .net, wrapper

Should a wrapper class be an instance class or a class with shared members? I need to create a wrapper class around a 3rdparty library, exposing just 2 functions and hiding all the complexity of the 3rd party class.

Comment: "it depends". Are the wrapped methods instance methods? In the process of hiding the complexity, do you need to maintain state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple rule here. If the class in the third-party library is an *instance class*, make your wrapper an *instance class*; if the class in the third-party is a *static class*, make your wrapper a *static class*. The idea of wrapper classes is generally to mimic structure, but simply hide complexity/advanced/unwanted functionality.

The only exception of which I can think is the case that the third-party library is poorly designed, and an instance class should really exist as a static class. Of course, if you are wrapping the functionality at such a level that *your wrapper function instantiates a new class*, it should really be declare within a *static class*.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the 3rd-party library... if it makes sense to have multiple separate instances of the lib with separate state, then an instance approach is suitable. If it is stateless methods, then a static/shared API would be appropriate.

Unless you need it to implement an interface, in which case it *has* to be instance-based.